# ¿Qué tengo que modificar en mi css para que sea un menú vertical?

Tags: css, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un menú hamburguesa, y el estilo que le puse lo manda de forma horizontal y no vertical. ¿Qué tendría que cambiarle a mi css para hacerlo de forma vertical?

Adjunto código:

```
.Cabecera{
    width:100%;
    background-color: black;
    padding:1em;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

    color:white; 
    }
    .Cabecera-a{
    color:white; 
      }
     .Cabecera-button{
    display:none;
    cursor: pointer;
       }
     .Cabecera-svg{
      width:2em;
      height:2em;
      fill:white;
    
      }
    .Cabecera-ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
     }
      .Cabecera-li{
      margin: 0 .5em;
      display: none;
     }
```

Estoy haciendo este menú en react y lo muestra de forma horizontal, no vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que colocarlo en la clase principal osea display:flex;

Comment: Ahh El with Colócalo en un 10% ya que como tienes el 100% se toma toda la pantalla
Avísame Si Te Funcionó

Answer (score 0):

intenta colocarle la propiedad `flex-direction: row` para colocarlo en vertical

Answer (score 0):

cambia el `flex-direction: row;` por el `flex-direction: column;`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction